# F# : A Class as an argument (Lucene.net 3.0.3)

Tags: f#

Let's say i have an instruction :

```
CharTermAttribute cattr = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
```

Note : CharTermAttribute.class is a class

In F#, it's could be like this :

```
let cattr:CharTermAttribute = stream.addAttribute(..........)
```

How can i say to F# that (CharTermAttribute.class ) is a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Lucene.NET expert, but if you are trying to call [this AddAttribute method](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d9/de7/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_util_1_1_attribute_source.html#a024db4fdac7177bbec9ccf0a55947ac8) then in the .NET version, this is a generic method and you can call it as:

```
let cattr = stream.addAttribute<CharTermAttribute>()
```

Comment: the method AddAttribute look like this :.

Comment: public virtual T AddAttribute<T>() where T : IAttribute
 {
 var attClass = typeof (T);

Comment: error : AddAttribute() only accepts an interface that extends Attribute

Comment: The caller must pass in a Class<? extends Attribute> value. Returns the instance of the passed in Attribute contained in this AttributeSource

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: AddAttribute() only accepts an interface that extends Attribute, but Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes.TermAttribute does not fulfil this contract.

Comment: This would suggest that it does: http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/apache/lucenenet/src/Lucene.Net.Core/Analysis/Tokenattributes/CharTermAttribute.cs

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ali Yacine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5886038/ali-yacine) question and the **error: AddAttribute() only accepts an interface that extends Attribute**, you must use interface of the types CharTermAttribute, etc in generic constraints of AddAttribute<> method. for example below:

```
var cattr = stream.AddAttribute<ICharTermAttribute>();
var another= stream.AddAttribute<IPositionIncrementAttribute>();
```